# Show full thumbnails in picture library

Tags: sharepoint-online, picture-library, thumbnail

The thumbnail images shown in the default view of a picture library in SharePoint Online are cropped if the image is too big, but our users want to see the full image scaled in the thumbnail to better identify them when all images in a folder are similar, but I can't find how to do this.

I've tried to create a new view with no luck, is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you which I have tested successfully.

First, click “Edit Page”.

[image]

Second, add a Script Editor web part.
[image]

Then, click “EDIT SNIPPET” to insert some JS code into this web part.
[image]

Next insert the JS Code below into it, this code will let your thumbnails displayed in the center.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var boxWidth = $(".ms-tileview-tile-content").width();
        var boxHeight = $(".ms-tileview-tile-content").height();
        var img = $("img.ms-positionRelative");
        img.attr("class", "");
        function DrawImg(boxWidth, boxHeight) {
            var imgWidth = img.width();
            var imgHeight = img.height();

            //compare the width and height
            if ((boxWidth / boxHeight) >= (imgWidth / imgHeight)) {

                //reset the width and height of img
               img.width((boxHeight * imgWidth) / imgHeight);
               img.height(boxHeight);

                //display img in center
                var margin = (boxWidth -img.width()) / 2;
               img.css("margin-left", margin);
            } else {

                //reset the width and height of img
               img.width(boxWidth);
               img.height((boxWidth * imgHeight) / imgWidth);

                //display img in center
                var margin = (boxHeight -img.height()) / 2;
               img.css("margin-top", margin);
            }
        }
        DrawImg(boxWidth, boxHeight);
    });

</script>
```

Last, click “stop editing” to save you change and you will see what you want.
[image]

Screenshot of result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, it's a possible solution, but it only works with classic mode. I need a solution for modern picture libraries.